# Gedit displays text, but cat tells a different story

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, less, text, newlines

I am trying to sort a dictionary from [Grady Ward's Moby](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html) and have encountered a bit of a problem. When I open it in gedit, I get:

```
abaca×N
abaciscus×N
abacist×N
aback×v
abacli×p
Abaco×N
abactinal×A
abaculus×N
abacus×N
abac×N
Abadan×N
Abaddon×N
Abad×N
abaft×vP
Abagael×N
Abagail×N
```

and so on.

However, 
`cat mobyposi.i | less`
tells a different story. I end up getting a mess of characters beginning with `<D7>` and ending in `^M` on every line and it's impossible to read.

`^M` is definitely a linebreak and dos2unix does not fix this. As far as the `<D7>`'s go, I'm completely lost. I need to be able to remove both of these to make this human-readable though I'm sure the machine can get through it just fine. :/

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Have you made sure that the file you have has been saved using UTF-8 charset?

Comment: I'm getting "unknown 8-bit"

Comment: Uh... Where? When? Doing what? I rather meant «make sure the file had been delivered to you in UTF-8 mode», not doing it yourself in fact. You still can force a file to be identified as UTF-8 but it has some limitations. See recode man pages for detailed information. Check the file's MIME type with `file -i <text_file>` before attempting to convert it.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I used `file -bi my-file.txt` and all it told me was that it's an unknown 8-bit file. As we speak I'm searching for solutions, though I've yet to find anything that will format this file the way I wish. Alternatives exist, though some of them don't even include the part of speech!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mobyposi.i` file uses old-style Mac line endings, i.e. CR characters. Why? I don't know. This file is from 1993, maybe the author wanted to be Mac-friendly and thought Unix and Windows users could fend on their own. Or maybe the author made a mistake, the `readme` file states that “the vocabulary file [has] CRLF (ASCII 13/10) delimiters” whereas the delimiters are actually just CR.

The words and the part of speech are separated by the byte D7₁₆ = 215₁₀ = 327₈. The `×` character that Gedit shows is the glyph corresponding to this byte in the Latin-1 encoding.

To convert the line endings to Unix line endings (LF) and the word/part separator to `:`, run

```
LC_CTYPE=C tr '\r\327' '\n:' <mobyposi.i >mobyposi.txt
```

`dos2unix` didn't do anything because the input didn't have DOS line endings. Gedit automatically detected a file in a foreign encoding (it detected the newlines, and detected a single-byte encoding and picked Latin-1 amongst the many possibilities because it was configured that way). Less doesn't automatically detect foreign encodings, it showed you what the file looks like when interpreted in your locale.